# Backup local storage from smartphone

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I made a webpage (todo app) that uses locale storage for saving the data in json format. I use it on my smartphone (android) so all data is stored locally on my device (ca 200 kB)

Now, I would like to backup the data somehow. I have tried different approaches (email, post form, copy-paste) but none of them has worked so far. Is there an easy straigt foreward way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have control over the localStorage to that extend. But there are several ways to store data across different storages (e.g. evercookie) even though I would not use that at all (not sure how legal that is, if at all)

But the best way would probably be to backup the data on your server and periodically let your users send their localStorage to you if there were changes.

If the localStorage got wiped, then just ask the server to send back the last stored set of data for that user.

If you are using Cordova/Phonegap you might want to look into http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.4.1/phonegap_file_file.md.html#FileWriter to create a copy of the localStorage as physical file.

Comment: Would i send the data with $.post() then?